Tailwind css doesn't function after deployed in vercel
A few days ago I am having the problem that my deploy does not show the css and tailwind styles and in my localhost its all right, I leave here my repository and my project. Please help
https://github.com/clemesilva/Ameterle2.git
I am trying toy deploy my project but a problem in the process is affecting me
I put this in my package.json to solve the vulnerabilities
"overrides": {
    "path-to-regexp": "8.2.0",
    "undici": "6.20.1",
    "debug": "4.3.7",
    "uuid": "11.0.2",
    "semver": "7.6.3",
    "tar": "7.4.3"
  }

Suppostly the problem is in this part, this is my tailwind.config.js
const { nextui } = require("@nextui-org/react");
const withMT = require("@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT");

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",

    "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // Agregar configuración personalizada para el carrusel
      fontFamily: {
        slick: ["slick"],
      },
      colors: {
        slick: {
          // Personaliza los colores del carrusel según sea necesario
          bg: "white",
          text: "black",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  darkMode: "class",
  plugins: [nextui()],
  tailwindcss: {},
};


I checked your repo on Github and you are missing postcss.config.js file in your root.
Add it in your root like this:
postcss.config.js
 export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
  },
};

Or run this command:
npx tailwindcss init -p

More info: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite

thanksss! thas was the problem, i solved!!!!

Happy to help, don't forget to upvote and accept this answer if it was correct!
